# nHibernate eager loading relationships from child sub-classes

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Say I have the following class definitions:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<OrderItemBase> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItemBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string OrderRef { get; set; }
}

public class ProductOrder : OrderItemBase
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class OtherOrder : OrderItemBase
{
    public virtual string MiscData { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With mappings along the lines of:

```
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    this.Id(x => x.Id);
    this.HasMany(x => x.OrderItems).Inverse().KeyColumn("OrderId").Cascade.All();
}

public class OrderItemMap : ClassMap<OrderItembase>
{
    this.Id(x => x.Id);
    this.Map(x => x.OrderRef);
    this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("OrderTypeId");
}

public class ProductOrderMap : ClassMap<ProductOrder>
{
    this.DiscriminatorValue(1);
    this.References(x => x.Product).Column("ProductId");
}

public class OtherOrderMap : ClassMap<OtherOrder>
{
    this.DiscriminatorValue(2);
    this.Map(x => x.MiscData);
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    // ... can't be arsed to type more code in here, you get the idea
}
```

**Now for the question bit:**

When I come to write a query for the order repository, I want some methods to eager-load all the OrderItems:

```
return this.All()
    .Where(o => o.Id == id)
    .FetchMany(o => o.OrderItems)
```

And some methods to also load the related ProductOrder Product items:

```
return this.All()
    .Where(o => o.Id == id)
    .FetchMany(o => o.OrderItems) // Ok so far...
    .ThenFetch(oi => oi.Product) // Uh-oh, the base order item doesn't have Product
```

How can I get a sub-classed item to eager-load it's relationship but only when I want it to?

Comment: (just a guess here) have you tried adding 'o is ProductOrder' to your Where clause?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - in this case, o will never be a ProductOrder, it's an Order. I would try adding another where clause after the fetch, but I was under the impression that you can't do that...